# How can I import related queries into SharePoint's search?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, configuration

I have a .csv with related queries on it that I exported from our old Google Search Appliance.  I would like to import these into SharePoint if possible, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is called in SharePoint and how to find it.  In case it's not called as such, what I basically want to do is:

A related query matches POS and Point of Sales.  If a user searches "POS", documents with "Point of Sales" should also come back.  Is this possible in SharePoint?  Is it also possible to import a .csv that contains all the related queries?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 it is called a thesaurus. You can import it using Powershell. See [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219579.aspx) for more details.